# What does "no X11 display variable was set, but this program performs an operation which requires it" error mean and how/can I fix it?

Tags: java

Here is a link to the project I am working on: http://goo.gl/myzeQQ
It works fine when I run it in Netbeans on my desktop(java 8) but gives me this error when I run it at the link above. It looks like the error might be due to the online compiler not being compatible with the JFrame graphics in some way.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your code is running in a headless environment (no GUI) yet you are creating and using a GUI.

It works fine on your computer because you have a GUI and everything required to display those graphical components.

You can fix/prevent this by creating a program that runs in the terminal and only accepts text input, or installing some sort of virtual gui on the machine that runs it.